# Create computed string column in C# Entity Framework migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a computed string column in a SQL Server database using C# and Entity Framework migrations. Here is my code from the model class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string FullName
{
    get { return FirstName + " " + Surname; }
    private set { }
}
```

All I get back in the database is a field called `FullName`, type `nvarchar(Max)`, with no computed column specification, it allows nulls

Comment: I don't believe the EF migrations will look at your C# code and translate that into a SQL expression. I believe you have to manually adapt the generate migration to make this SQL Server column a **computed** column

Answer (score 1):

First, replace the property definition like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Then create a migration and add this manually into the body of the `Up()` method:

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [FullName] AS ([FirstName] + ' ' + [SurName])");
```